# Padding not working in my Button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In my Button I have this XML:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFiltrarResultados"
    android:layout_width="18dp"
    android:layout_height="17dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-37dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
    android:background="@drawable/filtrar_explorar"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:padding="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtExploreTitulo"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.01999998" />
```

But I can't seem to be able to add padding to it. I've tried using `cropToPadding` or using `android:src` but nothing seems to help...

Comment: you have a button inside of your imageview?

Comment: Oh my god, I'm sorry, I mistook a Button for an ImageView, I've updated the quetion...

Comment: @AndréSilva maybe that https://stackoverflow.com/a/20545997/6352712 ?

Comment: There is likely another way to position the button than negative margins (which are technically unspecified behavior https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673503/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-negative-margins-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
android:layout_width="18dp"
android:layout_height="17dp"
```

and expect `padding 20dp`

Comment: Does that have to do with the problem?

Comment: Do you need negative margin?

Comment: I do, it's the only way I can set that in the position I want

Comment: see my edited answer, your button is too small to have padding 20dp

Comment: Why do you need padding in such a small button?

Comment: I need padding because I want its 'clickable area' to be wider without making the image bigger

Comment: This question has some nice pictures about padding vs. margin that may be relevant here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959050/android-beginner-difference-between-padding-and-margin  Padding is internal to the element, so if you have a height of 17dp and padding of 5dp on top and bottom you are left with only 7dp of content.

Comment: The clickable area is 18x17, can't get any bigger because you set it

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not a way to add image in button, as you did in your xml file`android:background="@drawable/filtrar_explorar"`. because by default background image try to scale as much as possible and ignore padding.So the good practice is use `ImageButton` with `android:src="@drawable/use_your_image"` and add `android:scaletype="fitCenter"`

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/use_your_image"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />
```