# How to create a circular Button or ImageButton or ImageView with a bitmap drawable and padding

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, xamarin.android, imagebutton

I can't figure out how to create a **Button** or **ImageButton** or **ImageView** or anything that has:

- A bitmap drawable with the icon
- A padding

What i have try now is this:

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ShowInstructionsImageButton"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Common_InformationIconContentDescription"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="14dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/normalTextColorPrimaryDark"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_info_bitmap"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Which works but the clickable area of the ImageButton is 20dp, how i can make the clickable area 48dp?

I have check this discussion here [Padding not working on ImageButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545742/padding-not-working-on-imagebutton) but if i use android:src instead of android:background i get a black box in the place of the icon

the icon is this:
[image]

Comment: That should be easy i guess. Just have the selector circular background without Bitmap . and keep the icon as src . If that doesn't not work pls add the drawable with question and also add expected output image .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me:

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ShowInstructionsImageButton"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Common_InformationIconContentDescription"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_margin="14dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/normalTextColorPrimaryDark"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_info_layer"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

with **ic_info_layer.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/ic_info_bitmap"
      android:width="@dimen/IconSize"
      android:height="@dimen/IconSize"
      android:right="@dimen/ButtonIconPadding"
      android:left="@dimen/ButtonIconPadding"
      android:top="@dimen/ButtonIconPadding"
      android:bottom="@dimen/ButtonIconPadding"
      />

</layer-list >
```

On API < 23 it is important the ImageButton to have fixed width and height because layer width and height is being ignored.

Comment: You can mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: This doesn't work for me: I only have the ic_info_bitmap that is visible, with a transparent background.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `MaterialButton`:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        style="@style/Widget.App.Button.IconOnly"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Circle"
        />
```

with:

```
<style name="Widget.App.Button.IconOnly" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton" >
    <item name="iconPadding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">12dp</item>
    <item name="iconGravity">textStart</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">3dp</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

and a circular shape:

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Circle" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Im getting an error that attr/cornerSize and attr/cornerFamily not found, Maybe Xamarin.Android does not have the same styles with Java, if you have use this code in Java

Answer (score 0):

First, try to use `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton` or `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView` instead of `ImageButton` to gain the advantage of backward compatibility.

After that, to show a drawable using it, you should use `app:srcCompat`, and not `android:background`. Now, if you add some padding to the view, it will be applied to the showing drawable.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ShowInstructionsImageButton"
    android:contentDescription="@string/Common_InformationIconContentDescription"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:padding="14dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    app:tint="@color/normalTextColorPrimaryDark"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_info_bitmap" />
```

Comment: when i use  app:srcCompat instead of background i get a black box in the place of the icon. my icon is a bitmap .png file

Comment: Is it possible to post the image?

Comment: i get the same result with android:src, i have post the image

Comment: I found out. The problem is `android:backgroundTint`. Replace it with `app:tint` in addition to using `app:srcCompat`.

Comment: im still getting the same black box, im starting to wonder if it is because im coding on Xamarin and it has to do something about it

Comment: So weird! Please replace `AppCompatImageButton` with `AppCompatImageView` and check it again.